# Java Synchronization when firing events

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a class like this (irrelevant code removed):

```
public final class Card {

    private boolean important;

    public boolean isImportant() {
        return important;
    }

    public void setImportant(boolean isImportant) {
        this.important = isImportant;
        fireIsImportantChangedEvent(isImportant);
    }

    private EventListenerList listenerList = new EventListenerList();

    private void fireIsImportantChangedEvent(boolean newValue) {
        for (CardListener listener : listenerList.getListeners(CardListener.class)) {
            listener.isImportantChanged(new CardEvent<Boolean>(this, newValue));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make this class thread safe and am not sure whether I need to synchronize any methods accessing important ( `public synchronized boolean isImportant() { ... }` and `public synchronized void setImportant(boolean isImportant) { ... }` ) or just declare important volatile ( `private volatile boolean important;` ).  It's my understanding that volatile would work if `setImportant()` didn't fire an event (if it just did `this.important = isImportant`) but will volatile still work if I do fire this event?

Comment: `volatile` will work as always, but the question is, do you want to prevent concurrent calls to `setImportant` while the event is being handled? If yes, you need `synchronized`.

Comment: Also, depending on how your EventListenerList is implemented, `fireIsImportantChangedEvent` might throw a concurrentModificationException if a listener is added/removed during the iteration.

Comment: EventListenerList is the one from swing [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html), which according the documentation provides "a degree of MT safety (when used correctly)" (I'm not sure what exactly this means).

Answer (score 1):

As of now, you do not need to do any synchronization. 
The event handling seems to happen in the same thread, unless the Listeners start new threads.
If that is the case, the you indeed need to think about visibility and synchronization.

If you want other threads to read the important value, then you need to make it volatile, otherwise it might get cached so that other threads do not see it.
With regards to synchronization, I do not see any need if the order of the listener invocation does not matter.
if you want to guarantee that a multithreaded change from false to true back to false fires first all true then all false events you need to synchronize. as of now it would be even sufficient to synchronize the fire method, as you are passing in the newValue, rather than to re-read it from the instance variable.